# How do I make selecting text and copy/paste work the same in bash as everywhere else?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

i.e. I want to use shift+arrows to select, ctrl+c/v to copy/paste. I'm also open to using another shell that makes this easier

Comment: "Everywhere else" must be Windows for you.  Ctrl-C has a much different meaning in *nix shells.

Answer (score 2):

bash uses the readline library to handle input. By default it uses emacs-style notation for commands.  See this [**cheatsheet**](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/) to get a list of commands on how to manipulate the command line with emacs-style notation.

If, instead, you would like bash/readline to use vi-style notation, then run `set -o vi` in your ~/.bash_profile

I'm not sure where "everywhere else" is, but both emacs and vi are pervasive in the *nix world.  If those two styles are not to your liking, you'll most liking have to look to another shell.